# Why checkbox is not being checked when clicking on its corresponding label element?

Tags: jquery, html

I have the following code in my html (Note that this html is produced by jquery ui) -

```
<input id="new_all" class="new_filter_button new_manufacturer_button ui-helper-hidden-accessible" type="checkbox" checked="checked" value="all" name="makes[]">
<label class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-disabled ui-button-text-icon-primary ui-state-focus" for="new_all" role="button" aria-disabled="true">
<span class="ui-button-icon-primary ui-icon ui-icon-makes"></span>
<span class="ui-button-text">ALL MAKES</span>
</label>
```

But when I click on label element then the corresponding checkbox is not checked. What's wrong with it?

Here is a snapshot.

[image]

Comment: What library do you use? jQuery-UI ?

Comment: do you have another element with `id="new_all"` in your "generated" document ?

Comment: Looks fine over here ~ http://jsfiddle.net/8ACL6/

Comment: yes i am using jQuery ui. no i dont have another element with `id="new_all"`

Comment: @user3779493 , here its fine Wats ur issue  ? http://jsfiddle.net/8ACL6/

Comment: @user3779493 , or u provide jsFiddle which doesnt work

Comment: @PratikJoshi you didn't include *jQuery UI* in this fiddle, so it simply shows html code

Answer (score 0):

if you are using same "Id" attribute for multiple element in a form than this is not possible.

Comment: multiple elements with same `name` is perfectly valid. Maybe you mean same `id` ?